# Create File Object in android fails

Tags: android, file-io

I want to write a file via FileOutputstream to the sd-Card of my phone. The directory is created correctly but the creation of the file itself fails. Here is my code:

```
File outputDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/scan");
            outputDir.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(outputDir, "image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            cameraView.setResolution(MAX_HEIGHT, MAX_WIDTH);
            cameraView.takePicture(outputFile);
```

The outputDir is readable and writable and the permission to write to external storage is set of course. When I check outputfile.exists() the result is false. And here is the error-message:

```
09-09 12:05:56.232: E/BitmapFactory(24467): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/scan/image_1441793154138.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
Here is what the cameraView Object is doing while taking the Picture:

```
public void takePicture(File file) {
    this.file = file;
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
}

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data,
        Camera camera) {
    mCamera.startPreview();
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: cameraView.takePicture(outputFile); first has to take the picture. And then the  user probably has to confirm that it is ok. And who would save it then? And where? If it cannot be saved then you should get error at save.

Comment: I edited the question to show what the takePicture method is doing.

Comment: And is onPictureTaken called? Is there a catch? You should place several log statements in it to find out what actually happens.

Comment: `And here is the error-message:`. You still did not tell when and on which code line you get that error.

Comment: `/BitmapFactory(24467): Unable to decode stream: ` ???? BitmapFactory??? There is no BitmapFactory in your code. And this does not look like saving.

Comment: My Problem is a different one than I first thought. Your hint about if onPictureTaken is ever called helped me to figure this out. Thank you. I will delete this question since it doesn't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        Bitmap bitmapToSave = params[0];

        File fPath = getAlbumStorageDir("FileName");
        File f = new File(fPath, "FileName" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".txt");
        String filePath = null;
        try {
            FileOutputStream strm = new FileOutputStream(f);
            bitmapToSave.compress(yourCompressFormat, 100, strm);
            strm.close();
            filePath = f.getPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return filePath;
    }
```